# After login, MSAL (Angular) does not redirect but URL has values

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular application that uses **Azure AD B2C** and the following libraries:

```
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.11.2",
```

The application similar to a [sample app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample).

I can login and see the claims in the **localstorage**.

But the URL is like

`http://localhost:4200/#state=eyJpZCI6ImJhNDcyZTRkLTZjOWQtNGQ4MS1hY2YzLTAzNGEw...`

and never redirected to the home `http://localhost:4200`.

The Redirect URL in Azure is `http://localhost:4200` and the redirect in the code is:

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: 'hidden',
      authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
      redirectUri: '/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
      knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain]
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wonderful and please update the redirect_uri http://localhost:4200 in the step 7 of this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa

Comment: I found out the issue. The redirected URL will have the data. The app needs to remove it. In the angular app, there is a route for ```state``` which takes the app to a different component. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular-b2c-sample-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts).